# Can't run Jupyter Notebook after updating python on MacOS Sierra 10.12.5

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

So I had `python 3.5` installed on my MacOS Sierra and got jupyter notebook installed via `pip3` and run properly. Recently, I updated to `python 3.6` and whenever I tried to run jupyter notebook and start a new notebook, the Kernel Error was happened with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 516, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 75, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 307, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 94, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 257, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 203, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5'
```

I've tried to uninstall `python 3.6` and install `python 3.5` via `Homebrew`. But I got this error when I run `jupyter notebook`

```
zsh: /usr/local/bin/jupyter: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6: no such file or directory
```

I don't know if there is any conflicts between Python versions in my macbook or Jupyter just isn't working with Python 3.6

**UPDATE 1**:
I tried to run `brew doctor` and here is the result

```
Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere with other software installs.
```

However, only python 2.7 is installed in that directory on my system. And I'm not sure if it's conflicted with python 3.6

Comment: First step if your Homebrew setup gets confused: `brew doctor`

Comment: @patrix I updated the question to show the brew doctor message